# how to write Objective C Wrapper for C++

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a burning question on writing objective C wrapper for c++. That is an error in my code when i try to build it. I'm not sure what i have do it wrong. Would truly appreciate any help or guide. The following is the sample code that i have written:

```
///Print.h///
int test1();

///Print.cpp///

int test1()
{
    printf ("hello man\n");
}

///cppWrapper.h///

struct Print;

typedef struct Print Print;

@interface cppWrapper : NSObject
{
    Print *print;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) Print *print;

-(id)init;

-(int)runTest;

///cppWrapper.mm///

#import "cppWrapper.h"

@implementation cppWrapper

@synthesize print = _print;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        _print = new Print(); //error occurred here. 
    }

    return self;
}

-(int)runTest
{
    self.print->test1();
}
```

Comment: At the very least you should include the details about the error in your question.

Comment: where is your `Print` struct declaration

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C wrapper for C++ is not implemented in terms of objective-C code.

To implement it, use pure C functions.

Under pure C functions, implement objective-C code. In C++ code, use C function to call objective-C code.

Objective-C does not understand C++.

Rather use Objective-C++ to use C++ code.

In objective-C++, you can use C++ code. Save your file as .mm rather than .m.

Edit:

The error in your code is because, the compiler is not able to find the definition of the structure. Compiler needs to know what is the size of the structure. Without its definition, it cannot create the object. This is also true even if you create object on stack.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment but in the code i'm already using Objective C++. please refer to my code cppWrapper.mm